# Cyclic subgroups dealing with prime numbers Question

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Let G be a group with |G| = pq. (p and q are both prime). 
How can we prove that every proper subgroup of G is cyclic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1) Lagrange's Theorem

2) A group of order a prime a number is **always** cyclic .